# APEX page process using a DB package

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I am using APEX 5.1.4

Know this is probably one of those very easy answers - just not sure what script is used in a Page Process to call a DB package. Know I need to pass the parameters and call the specific part of the package - just not sure what that page process script should be.

Need to pass in the values from page 3 - :P3_USER_ID (which is the user's email address) and the :P3_PASSWORD. The DB package is called PSPRT_AUTH_PKG and the part of the package is CREATE_ACCOUNT. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Think I found the answer...
use this in the page processing as PL/SQL code...

```
psprt_auth_pkg.create_account(:P3_USERNAME, :P3_PASSWORD);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like (you'll need to correct my made-up parameter names):

```
PSPRT_AUTH_PKG.CREATE_ACCOUNT
   ( p_user_id => :P3_USER_ID 
   , p_password => :P3_PASSWORD
   );
```